# Angular Ng-If Ng-Style not changing the table font colour

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following code which is an ionic list which populates the data retrieved. Im trying to colour code it into different colours based on the Status reponse.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="test in tests" class ="item-text-wrap" style="height:40%">

    <a href="#/tab/test/test-detail/{{test.ID}}">
    <div style="width:80%; float:left;">

    <table>
    <span ng-if="test.Status == 'Cleared'" ng-style="color:green">
    <tr>
        <td> <strong>Remark: </strong></td>
        <td style="padding:3px">{{test.Remark}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Status:</strong></td>
        <td style="padding:3px">{{test.Status}}</td>
    </tr>
        </span>
    </table>

</div>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But the colour of the table data still does not change. What could be the problem? Am i using the ng-if and ng-style wrongly? Thanks!

Update 1: Using the insights provided by @SSH, i updated my controller with the following codes:

Html:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="test in tests" class ="item-text-wrap" style="height:40%">

    <a href="#/tab/test/test-detail/{{test.ID}}">
    <div style="width:80%; float:left;">

    <table>
    <span ng-style="calculateStyle()">
    <tr>
        <td> <strong>Remark: </strong></td>
        <td style="padding:3px">{{test.Remark}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Status:</strong></td>
        <td style="padding:3px">{{test.Status}}</td>
    </tr>
        </span>
    </table>

</div>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.calculateStyle = function() {
      var style={}
      console.log('test3: '+$scope.tests.Status);
      console.log('test6: '+$scope.Status);
      if ($scope.Status == 'Cleared') {
      style.color='green';
      console.log('Viola');
    }
    else{
      console.log('GG');
    }
      return style;
  }
})
```

But the result returned in the controllers are still null/undefined. test3 and test6 returned me 'undefined' while the If statement returned me 'GG'. What could be the problem? Thanks!

**Update 2: Using SSH answers, i modified to the following:**

Html:

```
<span ng-style="calculateStyle(test)">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.calculateStyle = function(test) {
    var style={}
    if (test.Status == 'Cleared') style.color='green';
    return style;
}
```

But the test variable at the controller is still undefined. Using $scope.test doesn't work too. What could be the problem?

Comment: You don't need curly brackets around test.Status do you?

Comment: @JoeLloyd Yes i do, that is to populate the data retrieved from the controller.

Comment: You are not allowed to add a `<span>` element around `<tr>`. Why not using a css class ?

Comment: @JoeLloyd changed but still does not work , but thank you for the heads-up!

Comment: @MikeVranckx Lemme try using css class, thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do use it wrongly. You need to pass an object consisting of style names and conditions:

```
<span ng-style="{color:(test.Status == 'Cleared')?'green'}">
```

or better use a function in your controller to calculate and return style object, to keep your template clean:

```
<span ng-style="calculateStyle(test)">
```

and then in your controller definition

```
$scope.calculateStyle = function(test) {
    var style={}
    if (test.Status == 'Cleared') style.color='green';
    return style;
}
```

Comment: Hi, how do i use a function to return style object? Using $scope?  If you are free, could you kindly explain? Thank you!

Comment: Hi again, it does not work for the 1st solution you given mate. Thanks!

Comment: from the function at the controller , $scope.test.Status is returning me null value.

Comment: my bad -- I didn't notice your repeat statement... will change the code now

Comment: yes, I updated it straight away - you need to pass test as a parameter

Comment: Hi , so sorry for the late reply. If the controller is returning null, what's could be the problem?

Comment: U'll have to add ng-init="casectrl = case" ng-style="calculateStyle(casectrl)" . U might want to change the answer.