# Dynamically change color in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, styles, ionic2

Based on some condition, I am trying to set the color value of an element.

So, in my TS file, I have taken a variable called color that I am setting as

```
  if(this.value>0) this.color="#ffc000!important";
```

In my HTML file, I have tried setting this color in the following ways

```
<ion-icon name="notifications" [style.color]="color">
```

as well as using ngstyle

```
<ion-icon name="notifications" [ngStyle]="{'color': color}">
```

None of these are working. What am I doing wrong or what is the right way to do this?

Comment: possible you are missing space between your color code and `!important` so use `this.color="#ffc000 !important";` and check again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495014/angular-ng-if-ng-style-not-changing-the-table-font-colour -> perhaps this can work for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ion-icon name="notifications" [color]="color">
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 2):

**.HTML file Code to set background color**

```
<ion-col col-12 *ngFor="let item of newsArray" class="dir-col" >
          <div class="cell-dot" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': item.colorCode}"> 
     </div>
</ion-col>
```

**.ts file code to set dynamic color code from web service**

```
  this.totalSearchRecord = data["TotalNewsRecords"]
      for (let news of data["records"]) {
        this.newsArray.push({
          newsId: this.serviceProvider.checkNull(news['id']),
          newsTitle: this.serviceProvider.checkNull(news['PressReleaseTitle']),
          newsDes: this.serviceProvider.checkNull(news['PressReleaseShortDes']),
          newsDate: this.serviceProvider.checkNull(news['PressReleaseDate']),
          newsMonth: this.serviceProvider.checkNull(news['PressReleaseMonth']),
          alias: this.serviceProvider.checkNull(news['Alias']),
          colorCode:'#FFFFFF',
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/extend-ionic-add-custom-fonts-icons-ionic-config-json/48589/5?u=aravindhgopi)

> when we pass the name of the icon we want to use in the `name`
>   property ionic  adds the class for that icon based on the mode. For
>   example, if you pass heart:
>
> `<ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>`
>
> on iOS it would be:
>
> `<ion-icon class="ion-ios-heart"></ion-icon>`
>
> and for material design mode it would be:
>
> `<ion-icon class="ion-md-heart"></ion-icon>`

So that we can add CSS properties to them with the class name.

In your scss file,

```
.ion-md-heart{
        color: red !important;
    }
.ion-ios-heart{
        color: red !important;
    }
```

Hope this helps, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2 / Ionic 2 an easy way to change the color of objects is using the **theme/variables.scss** file.

```
// Named Color Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
// Named colors makes it easy to reuse colors on various components.
// It's highly recommended to change the default colors
// to match your app's branding. Ionic uses a Sass map of
// colors so you can add, rename and remove colors as needed.
// The "primary" color is the only required color in the map.

$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  my-special-color:   #ffcc55,
);
```

Now to change a color dynamically in a ionic2 page you can do this by binding the color to variable in the **HTML part**

```
<button [color]="myBtnColor">MyButton</button>
```

And in your **TypeScript part**

```
import { ..., ChangeDetectorRef, ... } from '@angular/core';
...
export class MyComponent {
  myBtnColor = "secondary"
  constructor(private changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  ...
  function changeColorDynamicaly() {
    myBtnColor = "my-special-color";
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
  ...
}
```

In my case the ChangeDetectorRef is used to see actual changes reflected in the view. The view is invalidated to be updated.